# Bootstrap3 modal dialog and responsive layout

Tags: modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

My modal dialog popup code based on Bootstrap3 looks like

```
<div id="responsive" class="modal fade" data-width="360" tabindex="-1" style="display: none; background:#57C1E9">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Search</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
        <form>
            <label for="keywords">Search</label>
            <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" placeholder="Search" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/125674

I have had all files attached based on directions from here" https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/ but somehow dialog box is getting resized to full width on responsive layout.

Any clue what I have missing? Does modal.js is built in Boostrap3 now?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using this instead of the default bootstrap modal?

Comment: Well, it just came up as first for google search when I have searching for 'bootstrap3 dialog box' :)